# Hibernate SQLServerException for username

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

I'm trying to run a java app that uses Hibernate and MS SQL Server Express.

SQL Server is configured with windows authentication as the login methond. I've also enabled TCP/IP port 1433(default), but I still keep getting the following error.

```
...// more output
at test.models.TestHibernate.main(TestHibernate.java:11)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'not required'. ClientConnectionId:de7daf69-2619-4906-b063-459a5b614bdb
...// more output
```

The line throwing the exception:

```
session.beginTransaction();
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=hibernatexml;integratedSecurity=false;</property>
        <property name="connection.username">not required</property>
        <property name="connection.password"/>
```

I removed other configuration errors but with this I'm out of ideas. If you need more info just let me know

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SQL Server is configured with windows authentication as the login methond.
>   jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=hibernatexml;integratedSecurity=false;

If you want to use [integrated authentication with SQL Server](http://vikdor.blogspot.in/2012/10/connecting-to-sql-server-express.html) from your java application, then

- the JDBC URL should have the `integratedSecurity` property set to `true`.
- the location of `sqljdbc_auth.dll` in the `Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver` installation should be set to the `java.library.path` JVM argument.
  e.g.

  ```
  -Djava.library.path="C:/Program Files/sqljdbc_4.0.2206.100_enu/sqljdbc_4.0/enu/auth/x64/sqljdbc_auth.dll"
  ```

Comment: I changed the authentication mode to user/pass and added those tho the `connection.url` as in your post, but it blocks (or maybe it takes too long, and i don't wait enough) when i call `getCurrentSession` on the `SessionFactory` object.

Comment: Did you try with that sample program that uses JDBC to see if the same happens with your SQL Server? If so, that JDBC program should throw "Connection refused" exception and there would be something missing in the SQL Server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the whole path for the DLL in java.library.path won't work, at least for Java 1.7. Your have to specify just the directory, with no ending "/".

e.g.:
(1) fail...

```
java -cp .;"C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar"
     -Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64\sqljdbc_auth.dl"
     ConnectMSSQLServer
```

WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.

(2) Ok!

```
java -cp .;"C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar"
     -Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64"
     ConnectMSSQLServer
```

Hope this helps,

Jose.